# Laravel dd() equivalent for struts 1.3

Tags: java, laravel-5, struts-1

I have been developing websites in Laravel for some time and now I have started developing in java struts. In Laravel there is a function **dd()**, which I can use to print anything and the execution stops there. **dd()** can print anything like object, array, string etc.

The function should do the following : 
1. print anything given like string, object, integer. 
2. It should stop execution.

Is there anything like **dd()** in struts/Java which does the same thing ?

Regards,
Tanvir